# Graph in python is not being plotted correctly

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have a piece of code which is supposed to plot a Gaussian distribution over bivariate data, using arrays and the imshow() function from pylab. My code looks like:

```
from pylab import *
x = zeros((101,101))
mean_i = 50
mean_j = 50
sigma = 10
max_ = 100
for i in range(101):
    for j in range(101):
        x[i,j] = max_*exp(((-(i-mean_i)**2)-(j-mean_j)**2)/(2*(sigma**2)))
for i in range(101):
    plot(i,x[i,50], 'rx')
show()
imshow(x)
show()
```

where my equation for `x[i,j]` is the product of the Gaussian for `i` and `j`.

If you run the code, you will see that two plots are produced; one is a colourmap of the `i/j` array, which should have a bright spot in the centre and decay away, as a Gaussian would, and the other is a plot of the `i` values for j=50, so should be a regular Gaussian curve.

This is not what happens. When I run the code, there are steps, like the data is not continuous when I feel like it should be. Why is this? Is it a problem with my equation, or my plotting technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously using python 2 and run into the usual problem of [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

The easiest way out is to make `sigma` a float,

```
sigma = 10.0
```

You can also cast the denominator to float

```
x[i,j] = max_*exp(((-(i-mean_i)**2)-(j-mean_j)**2)/float(2*(sigma**2)))
```

Or you can, at the beginning of your script, import the python 3 division behaviour:

```
from __future__ import division
```

and keep the rest the same.

I would also suggest to adapt your code to get rid of the for-loops. Also, importing everything from `pylab` is [not recommended](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean_i = 50
mean_j = 50
sigma = 10.
max_ = 100
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(101), np.arange(101))
x = max_*np.exp(((-(X-mean_i)**2)-(Y-mean_j)**2)/(2*(sigma**2)))

plt.plot(np.arange(101),x[:,50], 'rx')
plt.show()
plt.imshow(x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Changing sigma from 10 to 10.0 has fixed my problem. Such a simple solution... Thank you!