# 1/2 in python shell gives 0.5 while within a program, it gives 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple Question:

When I do 1/2 in python shell it gives float value

```
>>> 1/2
>>> 0.5
```

But

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 20):
    p = 1/i
    print(p)
    val = 2.0**p
    sum += val
    print(sum)
```

When  run this program, value of p always comes to 0.

What is the reason behind this behaviour. What am i missing?

Comment: [Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2958684/2301450), [Division in Python 2.7. and 3.3 \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21316968/2301450)

Comment: As that suggests, 1/2 in shell should also give 0. What is causing it to throw 0.5 in shell?

Comment: It sounds like your script is probably being executed by Python 2.

Comment: oh yes, you are right. Thanks for that. Already collected multiple downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you are using `python2.7`

in `python3` `1/2` will return `0.5`

to have the same results in `python2.7` use this:

```
from __future__ import division
print(1/2) # output 0.5
```

Or as suggested by @Mahi use:

```
p = 1.0/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the 1 in 1/i to (1.0)/i will make it work

Like this:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 20):
    p = (1.0)/i
    print(p)
    val = 2.0**p
    sum += val
    print(sum)
```

Or else, you could use ***p = 1/float(i)***
If the numerator or denominator is a float, then the result will be also.

This question is well discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0).