# multiplying 2 integers of the same value by 300 yields different results

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, division

I am trying to figure out why a difference of 283 happens when I decide to multiply rather than divide.

Here is some Python code from my terminal. As you can see both variables are integers, but depending on whether I divide one to get to the other or multiply the other changes the value slightly.

```
>>> type(times), times
(<type 'int'>, 1512296383)
>>> type(payout), payout
(<type 'int'>, 5040987)
>>> [times / 300 - payout, times - payout * 300]
[0, 283]
>>> [times / 300, payout, times, payout * 300]
[5040987, 5040987, 1512296383, 1512296100]
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Not correct: `//` is explicit integer division and behaves the same in Python 2 and 3; `/` is integer or floating point division in Python 2, depending on the argument types, and is explicit floating point division in Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-2-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), which discards everything after the decimal point. Since `times` isn't divisible by `300`, you'll get a truncated result. Here's a simpler way to see it:

```
>>> 1512296383 / 300 * 300
1512296100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that in Python 2.x, integer division does not return an exact floating point result. Casting one value to a float shows that the division does not exactly equal 300:

```
>>> float(1512296383)/5040987
300.0000561397996
```

Therefore when you do `1512296383/5040987`, you'll get the integer `300`, which will introduce a small error.

Comment: `1512296383.` or `5040987.`is enough.

Comment: @Kanak True, I did an explicit cast since I figured it'd be more helpful for the example in the question, since they'd need to do something like `float(times[0])`.