# Reversing a number failed in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

Please tell me what is wrong with my code.
The function returned `False` for the `palindrome(11)` and `True` for some cases.

Below is the code :

```
def palindrome(x):
    if(x < 0 or (x%10 == 0 and x != 0)):
        return False

    revertedNumber = 0
    while(x > revertedNumber):
        revertedNumber = revertedNumber * 10 + x%10
        x = x/10

    return(x == revertedNumber or x == revertedNumber/10)
```

Above code returned false for the input 11

Comment: Python 3 two kinds of division: division resulting in floats `/` and division resulting in ints `//`.  I suspect you were looking for the latter

Comment: On Python 2, `palindrome(11)` returns `True`, but it returns `False` on Python 3. You should be using `//` floor division, then it will work correctly on both versions.

Comment: Just tested according to the comments above. See this link with the results https://repl.it/@vperezher/TriangularWornUpupa

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot python uses two types of division.

Comment: FWIW, we've been able to invoke Python 3 division behaviour via a `__future__` import since Python 2.2, so there's no good excuse for using `/` when you need integer division.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division and the various linked questions there, as well as the questions linked in the duplicate target.