# Fractional numbers as array indices in the code, How it works?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, fractions

I'm having difficulty understanding this code(function) in Python.
I think the code below converts a two dimensional image array to a one dimensional buffer array.

However, in this case, I think fractional numbers could be inserted as array indices, because the index of 'buf' array is divided by 8.

```
(buf[(x + y * self.width) / 8] |= 0x80 >> (x % 8))
```

Could anyone explain me how the code works even it uses fractional numbers as array indices?

```
def get_frame_buffer(self, image):
    buf = [0x00] * (self.width * self.height / 8)
    # Set buffer to value of Python Imaging Library image.
    # Image must be in mode 1.
    image_monocolor = image.convert('1')
    imwidth, imheight = image_monocolor.size
    if imwidth != self.width or imheight != self.height:
        raise ValueError('Image must be same dimensions as display \
            ({0}x{1}).' .format(self.width, self.height))

    pixels = image_monocolor.load()
    for y in range(self.height):
        for x in range(self.width):
            # Set the bits for the column of pixels at the current position.
            if pixels[x, y] != 0:
                buf[(x + y * self.width) / 8] |= 0x80 >> (x % 8)
    return buf
```

Comment: Oops! sorry! good afternoon? good night?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

Comment: Thank you for your information!
I wish I could accept your comment too!
good early evening California!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a fractional number; when using Python 2.x, the expression `(x + y * self.width) / 8` will be evaluated as an integer division, resulting in an integer index - as long as `x`, `y` and `self.width` are also integers. Just as an example:

```
23 / 8 # 2.875, but the decimals get truncated
=> 2
```

By the way, to get the same result in Python 3.x, you'd have to use the `//` operator.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
nobody around me didn't know the answer.!thank you so much!