# What is the order of operations in Python?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

`print 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6`

Don't you have to do `%` second after `/`, `+`, and `-`?

Ex. 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + (0) - (.25) + 6 = 6.75

Does Python round up to the nearest whole number?

Comment: Are you asking why, in Python 2, the first line of your question gives 7 rather than 6.75?

Comment: yes, is that so, and how do i change that?

Comment: That's completely unrelated to order of operations. It's simply because python does integer division, so `1/4` equals 0.

Comment: Can't vote to close but here is a dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)