# data truncate when str(time.time()) in Python

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what happened when `str(time.time())` runs? It seems the data has been truncated, but it recovered when `float(str(time.time()))` runs. I'm so confused.

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: a = time.time()

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 1445007755.321532

In [4]: str(a)
Out[4]: '1445007755.32'

In [6]: a.__str__()
Out[6]: '1445007755.32'

In [7]: float(a)
Out[7]: 1445007755.321532
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/1317558/1860929

Comment: str truncate the value after the "." to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `str(a)` does **not** modify `a`, so there is no reason why `float(a)` should depend on `str(a)`. Maybe you wanted to reassign `a`?

```
a = 1445007755.321532
a = str(a)
float(a)
```

In this case the result *is* different:

```
>>> a = 1445007755.321532
>>> b = str(a)
>>> a == float(b)
False
>>> a, b, float(b)
(1445007755.321532, '1445007755.32', 1445007755.32)
```

---

Note that it holds that `float(x) == x` if `x` is already a `float`, so what you see is not surprising at all.

<sup>Even more: `float(x) is x` if `x` is of type `float`.</sup>

If you wonder why `str` seems to truncate the number it is because it returns a "human readable" representation of the value as a string.

If you want an "exact" representation use `repr`, or simply use a proper formatting function like: `"%.6f" % a` to control the number of decimal digits etc.

Comment: thanks,  I also find a post here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python  , which will be valuable for this answer, thanks a again.  @Bakuriu

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the number of digits after the decimal point is the difference between `str(f)` and `repr(f)`.

By default, the values are converted to string (before displaying in the `ipython` console), using `repr()`:

```
In [1]: class C:
   ...:     def __str__(self):
   ...:         return 'str'
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return 'repr'
   ...:     

In [2]: C()
Out[2]: repr

In [3]: str(C())
Out[3]: 'str'
```

btw, I can't reproduce your output on Python 3.4:

```
In [4]: 1445007755.321532
Out[4]: 1445007755.321532

In [5]: str(1445007755.321532)
Out[5]: '1445007755.321532'

In [6]: 1445007755.321532 .__str__()
Out[6]: '1445007755.321532'
```

But I can reproduce it on Python 2:

```
In [1]: 1445007755.321532
Out[1]: 1445007755.321532

In [2]: str(1445007755.321532)
Out[2]: '1445007755.32'

In [3]: 1445007755.321532 .__str__()
Out[3]: '1445007755.32'
```

Note: `float()` does NOT restore the precision here:

```
In [4]: float('1445007755.32')
Out[4]: 1445007755.32

In [5]: float(1445007755.32)
Out[5]: 1445007755.32
```

`float(a)` shows more digits in your question because `a` is already a float (it is probably a noop operation because floats are immutable):

```
In [6]: a = 1445007755.321532

In [7]: a is float(a)
Out[7]: True
```

i.e., `float(a)` may return the exact same object in this case.