# javascript int to string in python

Tags: string, int

It is maybe a silly question but I'm trying to translate a javascript sentence to python and I can't find a way to convert an integer to string like javascript.

Here the javascript sentence:

```
var n = 11;
n = n.toString(16);
```

It returns 'b'.

I tried chr() in python but it is not the same. 
I don't know to program in javascript so  I would be grateful if someone can help me to understand how does javascript convertion works to do that.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line

```
n = n.toString(16);
```

Is converting the number 11 to a string base 16 or 0xB = 11 decimal.

you can read more about [int.toString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)

the code you want is:

```
n = 11
n = format(n, 'x')
```

or

```
n = hex(n).lstrip('0x')
```

the lstrip will remove the 0x that is placed when converting to hex

Comment: Another approach is: `n = '%x' % n`

Answer (score -1):

Everything below was my original answer, didn't see it was base 16 instead of base 10. This is not the solution.

I wonder how much effort you took in searching for an answer: [Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python) was the first result when googling "python integer to string".
Taking a look at the search result, this should do it:

```
n = 11
n = str(n)
```

This might work too:

```
n = 11
n.__str__()
```

You can give it a try here http://progzoo.net/wiki/Python:Convert_a_Number_to_a_String

Comment: What I want is to get the same result that when I use toString() in javascript not to keep the n value as 11

Comment: Didn't see the the "16" and thought that the result "b" was an unwanted value from python code. Sorry for implicitly accusing you of being lazy.