# How can I replace a character with a number in a string?

Tags: python

How do I place a variable in `.replace()` in python. For example:

```
x = 2

example = example2.replace("1", x)
```

I think its clear what I am looking for, I just have no clue how to do it.

Comment: You need to call `str(x)`, you cannot replace a string with an integer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python

Answer (score 0):

My comments are based on Python v2.7:

In your code, "x" is assigned a integer value, they do not have replace method.
Instead, if "x" had carried normal string, then replace is available and this is how it works:

```
var2 = "palindrome syndrome"
print var2.replace("drome", "pal", 2)
```

> Output:
>
> palinpal synpal

In the statement, var2.replace, there are three arguments:
"drome" is the substring to find and replace with new string "pal" and do this for two occurrences of "drome".