# Not treating integers as strings in a list

Tags: python, list

Given this list:

```
>>> a = "123DJY65TY"
>>> list(a)
['1','2','3','D','J','Y','6','5','T','Y']
```

How can I produce a list where integers are not treated as strings? Like this:

```
[1,2,3,'D','J','Y',6,5,'T','Y']
```

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/961661/3077939) for conversion from string to int.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to convert each character that is a digit:

```
>>> a = "123DJY65TY"
>>> [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in a]
[1, 2, 3, 'D', 'J', 'Y', 6, 5, 'T', 'Y']
```

Comment: Thank you @niemmi!

Comment: @ShreyaGaddam You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all strings in a list containing only digits this way, using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
a = map(lambda char: int(char) if char.isdigit() else char, list(a))
```

For example:

```
In [3]: a = map(lambda char: int(char) if char.isdigit() else char, list(a))

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 'D', 'J', 'Y', 6, 5, 'T', 'Y']
```

[@niemmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043793/niemmi)'s solution using list comprehensions is probably a better approach given that we start with a string, not a list.

Comment: Why use  `map` when we have list comprehension?

Comment: That was just the first approach that came to mind. Given that we start with a string, not a list, the comprehension is probably a better approach. There are always a few reasonable ways to do something in Python :)

Comment: Yes, [TOOWTDI](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TOOWTDI) is not really true :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Right! :) Still beats Perl though.

Comment: No problem @ShreyaGaddam, glad to help!