# How to convert java byte[] to python string?

Tags: java, python, string

I know that java and python handle bytes differently so I am a little bit confused about how to convert byte[] to python string
I have this byte[] in java

```
{ 118, -86, -46, -63, 100, -69, -30, -102, -82, -44, -40, 92, 0, 98, 36, -94 }
```

I want to convert it to python string
 here is how i did  it

```
b=[118, -86, -46, -63, 100, -69, -30, -102, -82, -44, -40, 92, 0, 98, 36, -94]
str=""
for i in b:
    str=str+chr(abs(i))
```

But I am not really sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: `byte` is a datatype in java that does not correspond to python bytestrings. While you can get a result from this, it is likely meaningless.

Comment: If those bytes are stored in 2-complement, then you are destroying information by using abs()

Comment: See "[Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632)" for the minimal case of converting a single Python `int` to a `str`.

Comment: You were done converting it to Python when you typed `b=[118, ...]`. Your real question is probably more like "How do I convert a Python list to a string?", or maybe "How do I convert many Python integers to a string?". The first is probably either `str(b)` or `repr(b)`; the second is something like `' '.join(str(x) for x in b)`.  See also the docs for [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java `byte` type is a *signed integer*; the value ranges between -128 and 127. Python's `chr` expects a value between 0 and 255 instead. From the [*Primitive Data Types* section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of the Java tutorial:

> **byte**: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

You need to convert from 2s compliment to an unsigned integer:

```
def twoscomplement_to_unsigned(i):
    return i % 256

result = ''.join([chr(twoscomplement_to_unsigned(i)) for i in b])
```

However, if this is Python 3, you really want to use the `bytes` type:

```
result = bytes(map(twoscomplement_to_unsigned, b))
```

Comment: can also implement as `i % 256` (in python)

Comment: Martijn I noticed that you use a list inside the parenthesis when joining. So it's really faster than directly passing the gencomp to `join` right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: see [List comprehension without \[ \] in Python](//stackoverflow.com/a/9061024); for *`str.join()`* it is faster to pass in a list.

Comment: I already stumbled on it, hence my question. So long for "less signs and more letters". A lot of people would advise to remove them, but `join` creates the list anyway, only slower. BTW it must be the same performance issue with `"".join(map(chr,items))` then? this `map` function is really really useless nowadays.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: yup, `map()` has the same issue here.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation is highly inefficient.

I'd recommend to do that in a generator comprehension passed to `str.join` using an empty separator:

```
s = "".join([chr(abs(x)) for x in b])
```

edit: the `abs` bit is weird. It does what's requested, but nothing useful since `byte` is signed. So you'd need two's complement as in Martijn answer that fixes the next OP problem: data validity :)

It would be okay if you had some list of ASCII values in a table (and dropping `abs` allows us to use `map`, it's so rare to be able to use it let's not deprive us from doing so :)

```
items = [65, 66, 67, 68]
print("".join(map(chr,items)))
```

result:

```
"ABCD"
```

Comment: Would it be possibly more efficient to do `map(lambda x: chr(abs(x)), b)`?

Comment: I think it's equivalent. But as you say, passing absolute value of a negative byte is not recommended.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, it does nothing useful.

Comment: I got the joke! sorry I just copied the OP flawed code. fixed

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Did you think I was being serious? Sorry,  I was just kidding :) I was just trying to remind you.

Comment: no need to be sorry, I like jokes and I got that one! but the facts are here: the code was flawed so thanks. Don't want to leave upvoted flawed stuff on that site (recently deleted 2 answers with a +3 score. It hurts but that's life).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Python 3, bytes can already be initialized from a list. You'll need to convert the signed integers to unsigned bytes first.

```
items = [118, -86, -46, -63, 100, -69, -30, -102, -82, -44, -40, 92, 0, 98, 36, -94]
data = bytes(b % 256 for b in items)
print(data)  # b'v\xaa\xd2\xc1d\xbb\xe2\x9a\xae\xd4\xd8\\\x00b$\xa2'
```

If the bytes represent text, decode it afterwards. In your example, they do not represent text encoded to UTF-8, so this would fail.

```
data = data.decode('utf8')
print(data)
```