# Error when writing file

Tags: python, file-writing

I am trying to write numbers into a txt file.
But i get the error message telling me that the values have to be in string format not in int.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,6,4,3,2]
with open('writefile.txt','w') as f:
     for i in range(len(a)):
     f.write (a[i])
f.close()
```

Can someone help me ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please check the intends of your code. I think there are tabs xor spaces missing. And try a cast to a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python)

Comment: 1) `with` makes the call to `close` unnecessary. 2) In Python a loop over an iterable is done using `for item in a:`. The index `i` is not Pythonic.

Comment: for... in range(len(...)) is very unpythonic. Use for... in a instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here a short answer :
the value that you want is 'w' which is a string 
but in line 3-5 you are executing code for integer 
using the list,length and index of list 
Rather than this try to code:
write() with an string
Then It will work

Comment: The `w` is the mode that `open` shall use: write.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the int to a string before writing:

Replace:

```
f.write (a[i])
```

With:

```
f.write (str(a[i]))
```