# Python :Check condition in a number to starts with 130* in a list

Tags: python

Lets see i have a condition :

```
a = int(b) >= 1230 and int(b) not in [1300, 1305, 1250]
```

Here,the list could have multiple values `[1300,1303,1306,1307]` etc.
So i want to check:

```
if int(b) >= 1230 and int(b) = 130* and int(b) != 1250:
    do something
else:
    so something
```

How can i check for the numbers starting 130*?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it to add more details and what you have tried so far.

Comment: `(int(b) >= 1230) and (int(b) != 1250) and (str(b)[:3] == 130)`?

Comment: One way is to convert the number to str then use `str.startswith('130')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python)

Comment: `int(b) in range(1300,1310)` would detect if b is 1300-1309 ... you should convert `b` once before you you can avoid all those `int(b)` here and `int(b)` there ... if you have more then 4 or 5 values inside your list you want to compare b agains, use a `set(1300, 1305, 1250,1400,1500,1700,1999)` instead , its much faster that way. you could also test `intB // 10 == 130` to check if intB is 130* .

Comment: Do you mean int(b[:3])==130? But it cannot be 1250 of course. Condition int(b) != 1250 is meaningless here.

Comment: To be more clear, i have i am taking a value of 'b' from user and converting it to a int type. Then i am using the same value for my condition which is :a = int(b) >= 1230 and int(b) not in [1300, 1305] and int(b) != 1250.Here the list could be increased in future where i can have 1300,1301,1306,13006. so i want to freeze the check here by giving something called as 130*, where * can be any digit after 130.Is it possible to wild-card 13.0*?

Comment: What do you mean by  int(b) not in [1300, 1305] and i can have 1300,1301,1306? [1300,1305] is a range or list? Bounded or not?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
if int(b) >= 1230 and str(b).startswith('130') and int(b) != 1250:
    do something
else:
    do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a number is inside a [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) if you have a continious range to cover. 
Do not convert to int multiple times, store your int value: `bAsInt = int(b)` and use that.

If you want to check against specific single values, use a [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) if you have 4 or more values - it is faster that a list-lookup:

```
even = {1300,1302,1304,1306,1308}

for number in range(1299,1311):
    # print(number," is 130* :", number//10 == 130 ) # works too, integer division
    print(number," is 130* :", number in range(1300,1310), 
          " and ", "even" if number in even else "odd")
```

Output:

```
1299  is 130* : False  and  odd
1300  is 130* : True  and  even
1301  is 130* : True  and  odd
1302  is 130* : True  and  even
1303  is 130* : True  and  odd
1304  is 130* : True  and  even
1305  is 130* : True  and  odd
1306  is 130* : True  and  even
1307  is 130* : True  and  odd
1308  is 130* : True  and  even
1309  is 130* : True  and  odd
1310  is 130* : False  and  odd
```

---

**Take value from user and compare**:

Could be solved like so:

```
def inputNumber():
    # modified from other answer, link see below       
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input("Please enter number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
            continue
        else:
            return number

b = inputNumber()

even = {1300,1302,1304,1306,1308}

if b > 1230 and b not in even and b in range(1300,1310):
    #  r > 1230 is redundant if also b in range(1300,1310)
    print("You won the lottery")
```

It will print smth for 1301,1303,1305,1307,1309 (due to the `in even`) .

---

Other answer: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
def start_with(nub, start, stop):
    return [x for x in range(start,stop) if str(x).startswith(str(nub))]

print(start_with(130, 1, 5000))
```

use of this function you can find any list start with any number