# Trying to have a Python program quit with the letter "q", but input is an integer?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, ubuntu, integer

A quick snippet of the code below. I tried messing around with [another answer posted on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python), but it didn't seem to work at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Using Python 3 on Xubuntu 18.04 LTS. Here's the code:

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Your room is DARK, yet a light flashes red. What do you do?")
        print("")
        print("1. Look around.")
        print("2. There's a lamp somewhere...")
        print("3. Go back to bed.")
        print("")
        ans = int(input(">>> "))
        if ans == 1:
            print("")
            print("Too dark to see... better find a light...")
            time.sleep(2)
        if ans == 2:
            print("")
            print("Fumbling, you turn on your nightstand lamp...")
            break
        if ans == 3:
            print("")
            print("You sleep away the troubles... but you can't stay asleep...")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("")
            print("Back to the world of the living...")
        if ans == str('q'):
            sys.exit(0)
    except ValueError:
        print("")
```

So, when the user inputs "q", I want the program to close. I can't seem to get it to do it at all.

Comment: `ans = int(input(">>> "))` - this is trying to convert it to an integer. Therefore you'll never get `ans == str('q')` (also note `str('q') == 'q'`...)

Comment: Why convert to an integer at all? Leave it as a string and compare with "1", "2", "3" and "q".

Comment: I have to admit I feel like a complete idiot. I don't know why I was converting everything to an integer. Having it as a string is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your line where you say `int(input(">>> "))` which is converting what the user enters to an integer each time. What you should do is take in the user input as a string and then check if it is a valid number for 1, 2, & 3 or if it equals q.

Example:

```
ans = input(">>> ")
if ans == '1':
    # Do something
elif ans == '2':
    # Do something
elif ans == '3':
    # Do something
elif ans == 'q':
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're typecasting the q to an integer at input: `ans = int(input(">>> "))` and then trying to typecast it back to a string at `if ans == str('q'):` Better solution would be to keep the input as a string in ans (remove the `int()` typecast and explicitly typecast it as an int with `int()` in each case.

**Update:** My original solution was wrong. The corrected one asks if the string is a digit and then evaluates it as an int. This is more verbose and I therefore recommend Karl's solution. But in case you're wedded to typecasting the string as an int I'm leaving this posted.

```
while True:
try:
    ans = input(">>> ")
    if ans.isdigit() and int(ans) == 1:
        ...
    elif ans.isdigit() and int(ans) == 2:
        ...
    elif ans.isdigit() and int(ans) == 3:
        ...
    elif ans == 'q':
        sys.exit(0)
except ValueError:
    print("")
```

Then you don't even need to call `str()` at all.

Comment: This is the best solution, I feel. Thank you. All of you are right, though, it's silly to try and do it the way I was. I feel like a total moron. lol But thank you for your help!

Comment: My solution is wrong.

Comment: @M. I will delete this answer soon. But it is wrong. Entering q would cause an error because I'm typecasting a letter into a number.

Comment: @M. I corrected it. But my recommendation is to stick with Karl's answer.