# Create a list of variables

Tags: python, variables

How can I create a list of variables in python. for example how can I create the following variables f_1, f_2, f_3, ..., f_100. I want to make them with 'for' loop. is there a function that I can use in this specific problem?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to create many separately named variables, rather than just use a list object (e.g. `f`) that you then index by number (e.g. `f[3]`)?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string

Answer (score 0):

how about a dictionary?

```
numd = {}
for i in range(100):
    numd["f_{}".(i)] = 0
```

or just make a list then add the values there with a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Using map and range; coercing integers to strings in the lambda function and prefixing the numeric with "f_":

```
[*map(lambda x: "f_"+str(x), [*range(1, 100)])]
```

Using a for loop:

```
numeric_range = [*range(1, 100)]
lst = []
for i in numeric_range:
    lst.append("f_"+str(i))
print(lst)
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
["f_"+str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to assign new variables dynamically, you could run an assignment command via the `exec` function, for example:

```
for i in range(100):
    value = i * 2
    var_name = "f_{}".format(i)
    exec("{} = {}".format(var_name, repr(value)))

print(f_30)
```

However, you would need a very strong and specific reason to want to do the above.

The normal expectation would be that you simply put the values into a single `list` object, and access it by index number.  For example:

```
f = []
for i in range(100):
    value = i * 2
    f.append(value)

print(f[30])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with it that they are created in the global namespace then you could also use the following code:

```
for i in range(100):
    globals()["f_"+str(i)] = 0
```

`globals()` gets you a dictionary of the names defined in the global namespace.