# How to return a string containing the integer x repeated y times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that takes two integers x and y. And it should return a string containing the integer x repeated y times.

My code:

```
def repeat_int_str(x, y):
    int = "x" * y
    return int
```

What the result is supposed to look like:

```
assert(repeat_int_str(0, 4) == "0000")
assert(repeat_int_str(-5, 3) == "-5-5-5")
```

Comment: What did you do to trace the problem?  For instance, what is that *actual* value of `"x"`?  That's where you made your error.

Comment: [Converting integer to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

This code is close to being workable, few insights:

1. Use `str()` to convert int to string
2. Then, as you discovered, multiplying string by int would make it duplicate as a repeating string
3. Don't use `int` as a name for a variable ([it's a builtin class for integer numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int))

```
def repeat_int_str(x, y):
    val = str(x) * y
    return val

# All the following pass
assert repeat_int_str(0, 4)  == "0000"
assert repeat_int_str(-5, 3) == "-5-5-5"
```

Comment: just a small correction: `int` is **not** a reserved keyword. The fact that it *can* be used as a variable name shows that it is not a reserved keyword (compare with what happens when you try to use `class`, `def`, `if` etc as a variable name). `int` is merely a built-in  `class`

Answer (score 1):

what you forget to do is turn x to a string. `'x'` won't do, this just gives you the letter x as a string.

try the function `str(x)`.
like that:

```
def repeat_int_str(x, y):
    int = str(x) * y
    return int
```