# How do I check for an integer in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

I have a text file to save data
and I put many numbers in the text file for example

---

**how do I check if the given number is already exists in the text file??**

---

I tried many different ways like:

```
def check_if_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            if string_to_search in line:
                return True
    return False
```

But in this case the string_to_search can not be integer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python

Answer (score -1):

In your example, `string_to_search` can be converted from an `int` to its `str` representation using `str()`:

```py
def check_if_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            if str(string_to_search) in line:
                return True
    return False
```

if `string_to_search` is already a `str`, it will have no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is a good starting point. Depending on exactly what sort of file you are reading and its contents (which isn't specified), there are a few approaches which may work:

1. Before calling your function with an integer value, convert it to a string with [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

```py
check_if_string_in_file(file_name, str(123))
```

Note that this approach falls short if e.g. your file has a line like "12345", as `'123' in '12345'` is true. You can resolve this by using a more strict check (instead of just `in`).

2. If you know that all the lines in your file will just be numbers, you can convert the line to number after reading it in using the `int` function:

```py
def check_if_string_in_file(file_name, number_to_search):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            line_as_int = int(line.strip())
            if number_to_search == line_as_int:
                return True
    return False
```

If you plan to do several such checks, it may make sense to read the whole file into a list in one shot and then check for the target in the list.