# how do you change an integer to a string in python?

Tags: python, string, integer

i'm trying to code a game but it keeps popping up with `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` and i tried `print('sample text' + variable + 'sample text')`

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python

Comment: E. g. something like "str(5)"

Comment: if python 3 you can use f-strings i.e. `print(f'sample text {variable} sample text')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting integer to string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can either cast to `str` or use an f-string (format string).

`print('sample text' + str(variable) + 'sample text')`

or

`print(f'sample text {variable} sample text')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it with string using `print(str(variable))`.