# How to define variable with two zeros

Tags: python, variables

I making MAC addr generator and currently I have this problem.

```
mac1="001122334455"
mac2="001122334695"

mac1 = [mac1[x:x+2] for x in xrange(0,len(mac1),2)]
mac2 = [mac2[x:x+2] for x in xrange(0,len(mac2),2)]
k=0
for item in mac1:
    mac1[k] = "%d" % int(mac1[k], 16)
    mac2[k] = "%d" % int(mac2[k], 16)
    mac1[k]=int(mac1[k])
    mac2[k]=int(mac2[k])
    k=k+1

while mac1 != mac2:
    #print mac1

    print "%X0:%X:%X:%X:%X:%X" % (mac1[0], mac1[1], mac1[2], mac1[3], mac1[4], mac1[5])
    mac1[5] = int(mac1[5]) + 1
    if int(mac1[5]) > 255:
        #mac1[5] = 00
        mac1[4] = int(mac1[4]) +1
        if int(mac1[4]) > 255:
            mac1[3] = int(mac1[3]) + 1
            if int(mac1[3]) > 255:
                mac1[2] = int(mac1[2]) +1
                if int(mac1[2]) > 255:
                    mac1[1] = int(mac1[1]) +1
```

I need to start generating fifth byte from beginning so I defined mac1[5] = 00, but instead of two 0 I only get one 0?

Comment: Replace `"%X0:%X:%X:%X:%X:%X"` with `"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X"` - but also see my a little bit shorter solution.

Comment: It's easier to take string slices than to do a bunch of shifts and mods - see solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler to just treat the entire mac as one number:

```
mac1 = 0x1122334455
mac2 = 0x1122334695
for i in xrange(mac1, mac2+1):
    s = "%012x" % i
    print ':'.join(s[j:j+2] for j in range(0,12,2)))
```

See [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an integer as `00` it will always degrade to `0`, added to that fact, in python 2.x putting a `0` in front of an integer (for example `0123`) will tell python you want that number evaluated as an `octal`! defiantly not what you want. In python 3.x, `0integer` is not allowed at all!

you need to use strings if you want `00` instead of `0`.

Out of interest, are you trying to generate a range of macs between `mac1` and `mac2`, if so I suspect i have a more elegant solution if you are interested.

---

EDIT:

Working solution will print the hex values of the mac address between start and finish, since it works internally with integers between `0 and 255` the `start` and `end` values are integers not hex values.

```
start = [0,11,22,33,44,55]
end =   [0,11,22,33,46,95]

def generate_range(start, end):
    cur = start

    while cur < end:     
        cur[5] = int(cur[5]) + 1

        for pos in range(len(cur)-1, -1, -1):
            if cur[pos] == 255:
                cur[pos] = 0
                cur[pos-1] = int(cur[pos-1]) + 1

        yield ':'.join("{0:02X}".format(cur[i]) for i in range(0,len(cur)))

for x in generate_range(start, end):
    print (x)
```

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do that. Any info how to do that more elegantly would be good.

Comment: I'm noticing you're comparing to `255` yet you have 2 positions, I assume you're using hex numbers as well?

Comment: 00:11:22:33:0x54:0x51  Got output like this

Comment: @user1065214 yes, unfortunately I do not know how to solve this at the present time, I will continue researching it, but for now this code is more to help you along with a solution than being one, hopefully that will change soon though.

Comment: @user1065214 and fixed! solution is now working, have fun with it.

Comment: Thanks :) will try to understand it