# How to guess the 4 digit secret code entered by user(unknown to us)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

can someone explain how to do this in python? the idea is to figure out the 4 digit code(ex: 3968) entered by the user. how would one design an algorithm to go about finding this?
here is what i got..:

```
code=int(input("Enter 4 digit secret code:"))
count=0000
while(count!=code):
    count=count+1
print("Your code was",count)
```

this works perfectly....Except when the code starts with 0... Ex: 0387
it prints " Your code was 387" as appose to 0387

whats a quick fix for this?

Comment: This question actually was asked previously, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/134934/1165330 for answeres.

Comment: `print("Your code was", code)`

Comment: Also, you should never, ever, store anything as an int (or float) unless you intend to do arithmetic with it. This is a perfect example why this is so. Phone numbers, post codes etc. are not numbers, they are strings and should be treated as such.

Comment: Increasing it with 1 is arithmetic, though. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: But the algorithm can't be changed to cope with an alphabetic code like `ABCD` as a result.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: OK, but the entire example is quite contrived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print("Your code was %04i" % count)
```

The % means that here comes a variable.
The 04 means zero-pad it to four characters.
The i means it's an integer. [Docs here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Alternative version, using the new, more flexible [`.format()` formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
print("Your code was {:04n}".format(count))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to print it with some formatting:

```
print("Your code was {0:04d}".format(count))
```

which will zero-pad your number up to 4 digits. See the [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) documentation for more details.

Alternatively, you can use the [`str.zfill()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to add the extra zeros after string conversion:

```
print("Your code was", str(count).zfill(4))
```

Comment: Hah! I beat you with two minutes! :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: but without documentation! I hesitated if I should add an answer, but since yours was so very basic and lacking any explanation, I did so anyway. :-P

Comment: Right, I should add doc links. I did add the format formatting for completeness even though I don't like it. :)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I am coming round to it; it *is* more flexible, and supports mixing positional and keyword parameters.

Comment: **Too** flexible. I had some horror show example somewhere. It's very easy to obfuscate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it purely using strings:

```
import itertools

code = input("Enter 4 digit secret code:")

for attempt in itertools.product("0123456789", repeat=4):
    attempt = ''.join(attempt)
    if attempt == code:
        print("Your code was", attempt)
        break
```

Comment: Nope! "count" should be "attempt" in print statement other then that it works although the printed result is a comma separated list..
to fix this i just did this:


    if j == code:
        print("Your code was",j)
        break
it now prints it as one string no spaces or commas :D