# Add leading Zero Python

Tags: python, string

I was wondering if someone could help me add a leading zero to this existing string when the digits are sings (eg 1-9).  Here is the string:

```
str(int(length)/1440/60)
```

Comment: How many leading zeros?

Comment: just one. so the digits would be 01, 02, etc.

Comment: // , This isn't a duplicate, since this refers to actually changing the variable's value, not just displaying it differently. The difference is important, since only some of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros would meet this need.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`str.zfill`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) method, like this

```
my_string = "1"
print my_string.zfill(2)   # Prints 01

my_string = "1000"
print my_string.zfill(2)   # Prints 1000
```

From the docs,

> Return the numeric string left filled with zeros in a string of length
>   width. A sign prefix is handled correctly. The original string is
>   returned if width is less than or equal to len(s).

So, if the actual string's length is more than the width specified (parameter passed to `zfill`) the string is returned as it is.

Comment: so nice. if u need a trailing 0 only for single digit numbers str.zfill() will just add to those who actually are singe digits. 7 becomes 07, but 10 would stay 10 and not become 010, for example.

Answer (score 27):

Using [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) or [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format), you don't need to convert the number to `str`:

```
>>> format(1, '02')
'01'
>>> format(100, '02')
'100'

>>> '{:02}'.format(1)
'01'
>>> '{:02}'.format(100)
'100'
```

According to the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format) documentation:

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and
>   should be preferred to the % formatting  ...

Comment: But what if I have a string like `a = "abc"`, then `format(a, "05")` doesn't work

Comment: @winklerrr, For non-number, use`format(a, '>05')`.

Comment: @winklerrr that question is not relevant to the original question. This question isn't about validating input, it's about modifying current data.

Comment: @dmcoding that's why I added a comment (for which I directly got an answer). So what's your problem here?

Answer (score 16):

**I hope this is the easiest way:**

```
 >>> for i in range(1,15):
 ...     print '%0.2d' % i
 ...
 01
 02
 03
 04
 05
 06
 07
 08
 09     
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 >>>
```

Comment: // , His question was about how to deal with this in an actual variable, not just with printing.

Comment: This is a better answer in general.