# python 3.4 string manipulation - truncating leading zeros

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, zero, truncation

There are a number of existing posts on this topic, but I cannot get this simple piece of code to work correctly. I have tried many many times with no success...

```
per = 5


if per < 10 == True:
    ms = 'fwd_%sd' % str(per).zfill(2)
else:
    ms = 'fwd_%sd' % per
```

and

```
if per < 10 == True:
    a = format(per, 'fwd_02d')
else:
    a = 'fwd_%sd' % per
```

The result should be 'fwd_05d' but I can only get 'fwd_5d'.

Among others, I have seen:

[Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

[Add leading zero python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620602/add-leading-zero-python)

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use str.format, if you are actually doing nothing else but padding just use  `ms = 'fwd_{:02}d'.format(per)` and forget the if/else, only numbers less than 10 will be padded with a 0. The 0 in `{:02}` is what to pad with and the 2 is the size to pad to.

```
ms = 'fwd_{:02}d'.format(per)
```

On another note `if per < 10 == True:` is the same as `if per < 10:`

Comment: Why do we even need `if` here?

Comment: @tuananh, why would we not? Maybe there is more logic in the OP's code

Comment: Because `'fwd_{:02}d'.format(50) = 50, 'fwd_{:02}d'.format(500) = 500`

Comment: @tuananh, the question about leading zeros,  I have no idea what the OP is actually doing so I used the code provided

Comment: thanks very much Padraic and Martijn, much appreciated. Not sure where my older comments went.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a temp str variable, check if less than 10, and add a zero to the front if needed. Also, you shouldn't have an if statement and then check if it equals true. It is redundant and makes your code less readable.

```
per = 5

if per < 10:
    perStr = '0' + str(per)

print('fwd_' + perStr + 'd')
```