# number string to list of numbers conversion

Tags: python, string, list, int, type-conversion

I have a string

```
a = 2,00,02
```

each element of this string has datatype `str`.

I want to convert it to a list such as `a = [2, 00, 02]` so `a` is a `list` and each element of a should have datatype `int`

what I did is `a = [int(each) for each in a]` which gave me `a = [2,0,2]` where a is a list and each in a is an integer.
But that's not what I was trying to do. I want `a = [2, 00, 02]` where middle `0` should be `00` and last `02` should be `02` only and not as 0 and 2.
How should I do this?

Comment: If you want each of them to be an `int` then you cannot expect `'00'` to be stored as `00` in `int`

Comment: Could you rephrase your needs? `02 == 2`. This is only a matter of output formatting. And by default, Python does not shows leading zeros. Are looking for `"{:02d}".format(...)` ?

Comment: If want a `list` of `int` type data then you can not have `00` or `02` by the way.

Comment: @Sylvain yeah.. I was looking for the way to represent it in 2 digits.

Comment: You need to rewrite this question so it makes sense. You can't possibly have a string `a = 2,00,02`, because that's not a string; that's a tuple of 3 ints in Python 2.x, and a syntax error in Python 3.x. Also, each element of a string is a single-character string. So, what do you _actually_ have? Is it 'a = '2,00,02'`? Or `a=('2', '00', '02')`? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

`00` is the same number as `0`.

```
In [59]: 00 == 0
Out[59]: True
```

But Python will always represent this number as `0`, never `00`. If you want to preserve `00` then you must use strings:

```
In [56]: a = '2,00,02'

In [57]: a.split(',')
Out[57]: ['2', '00', '02']
```

If you want to convert `a` to a list of `ints` while also preserving the leading zeros, then you'll need to keep track of two lists:

```
In [65]: astr = a.split(',')

In [66]: astr
Out[66]: ['2', '00', '02']

In [67]: aint = map(int, astr)

In [68]: aint
Out[68]: [2, 0, 2]

In [69]: zip(astr, aint)
Out[69]: [('2', 2), ('00', 0), ('02', 2)]
```

Use `aint` for numeric computations, and `astr` for string formatting/output.

---

Note that leading 0's in Python are used to represent octal numbers:

```
In [62]: 011
Out[62]: 9
```

since 11 base 8 is 9.

So if the string was `a = '2,011,02'`, then you'll need to clarify if you want the integer values `[2,11,2]` or `[2,011,02]` which is equal to `[2,9,2]`.

```
In [70]: [2, 011, 02] == [2, 9, 2]
Out[70]: True
```

And if your string was `a = '2,09,02'`, then if you convert each numeric string to an int you'd get `[2, 9, 2]`, but if you want `[2, 09, 02]` then you'd get a `SyntaxError` since `09` is not a valid octal number.

Comment: He wants __int__ in list not __string__ and sounds like it is impossible .

Comment: Ints are not saved with leading zeroes, for the string representation, look at this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3371180/3216660

Comment: The OP didn't say whether this was Python 2 or Python 3; in Python 3, leading 0's no longer represent octal numbers; they're a syntax error. (To represent octal numbers in both 2.x and 3.x, use `0o11`.)

Comment: Meanwhile, the way to convert strings like `'09'` to decimal integers (in both 2.x and 3.x) is to call `int` with an explicit base: `[int(x, 10) for x in astr]`.