# How do you create a list of values in Python within a certain range?

Tags: python

I want to create a list of values that each start with TI and range from 00000-50000. Any idea of how to do this in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display number with leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: `range`/`xrange` with `str.%`/`format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `zfill`

demo:

```
>>> [ str(x).zfill(5) for x in range(10) ]
['00000', '00001', '00002', '00003', '00004', '00005', '00006', '00007', '00008', '00009']
```

demo with `IT`:

```
>>>[ 'IT'+str(x).zfill(5) for x in range(10) ]
['IT00000', 'IT00001', 'IT00002', 'IT00003', 'IT00004', 'IT00005', 'IT00006', 'IT00007', 'IT00008', 'IT00009']
```

you can also use `format`:

```
>>> [ '{}{:05d}'.format('IT',x) for x in range(10) ]
['IT00000', 'IT00001', 'IT00002', 'IT00003', 'IT00004', 'IT00005', 'IT00006', 'IT00007', 'IT00008', 'IT00009']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ll = ['TI' + '%05d'%x for x in range(50001)]
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation for your answer?