# Padding with zeros in the middle of a string?

Tags: python-3.x, text, format

Padding a number with leading zeros has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros). But in my case I have a string character followed by digits. I want to add leading zeros after the string character, but before the digits, keeping the total length to 4. For example:

```
A1 -> A001
A12 -> A012
A123 -> A123
```

I have the following code that gets me what I want, but is there a shorter way to do this without using re to split my string into text and numbers first?

```
import re
mystr = 'A4'
elements = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", mystr, re.I)
first, second = elements.groups()
print(first + '{:0>3}'.format(second))

output = A004
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to avoid using `re`:

```
def pad_center(s):
    zeros = '0' * (4 - len(s))
    first, *the_rest = list(s)
    return first + zeros + ''.join(the_rest)

print(pad_center('A1'))
print(pad_center('A12'))
print(pad_center('A123'))
```

Or, if you want to use `format()` you could try this:

```
def pad_center(s):
    zeros = '0' * (4 - len(s))
    first, *the_rest = list(s)
    return '{}{}{}'.format(first, zeros, ''.join(the_rest))
```

However, I am not aware of any way to add padding to the center of a string with the [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) without prior processing.

Comment: @Murchak sorry, not that I know of, but see my updated answer.