# Need to add a zero in front of the minute when minute < 10 minutes Python

Tags: python, if-statement, time, minute

```
    if EndTimeMinute < 10:
        EndTimeMinute = EndTimeMinute
```

Need to add zero here

Currently the result is just coming out as a single digit. So the time is going out to `1:1`. I need to make it so that my code bring out the time as `1:01`.

Comment: `EndTimeMinute = EndTimeMinute`?! Pad it with a zero by string concatenation.

Comment: `EndTimeMinute` holds a number but you want to change the textual representation (as a string). This information is not contained in the number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: Just try it with this code: print "%02d" % (1,) and % is like printf or sprint.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it into a string.

Pad it with

```
n = 7 # Example

if n < 10:
    result = '%02d' % n
else:
    result = str(n)
print result
```