# How to write a number for example 9, into 09?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a python program which as input takes a date(for example 09-11-2001) and as output give (10-11-2001).
But the thing is that if i have (f.e. 04-04-1992), i need as output (05-04-1992)
not (5-04-1992).
So how do i write a number,for example 9, into 09 and the opposite?
And how do we sum 04 and 03?

Comment: If it's a date then why aren't you using `datetime`, which already knows how to handle them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)