# Time efficient way for add leading zeros in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner in python. I'm using python 3.X in my windows 7
I have a pandas series. Currently it contains 1544252 records of 8 digit number of int64 type. Sample of last few records are given below

```
1544241    87526878
1544242    92480921
1544243    61479211
1544244    57572826
1544245    25527504
1544246    69477558
1544247    35477532
1544248    12475315
1544249    75480854
1544250    68527476
1544251    87480808
```

I need to add leading zeros in my series to make 8 digit number to 10 character long string. Here is my desired output.

```
    1544241    0087526878
    1544242    0092480921
    1544243    0061479211
    1544244    0057572826
    1544245    0025527504
    1544246    0069477558
    1544247    0035477532
    1544248    0012475315
    1544249    0075480854
    1544250    0068527476
    1544251    0087480808
```

Can you please suggest me how to do that in time efficient way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _how to do that in time efficient way?_ What inefficient ways have you been trying?

Comment: Try the below link to know how to add leading zeros 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = pd.Series(map(lambda x: '%010d' %x, s))
```

where `s` is your series.

Answer (score 2):

If you series is called `s`

```
'00'+s.astype(str)
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
df['tendigits'] = df['eightdigits'].apply(lambda n: '00' + str(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zfill` function which left-pads with leading zeros and takes as an argument the witdh of the desired output.

If `s` is your series, you can do:

```
s.apply(lambda x : x.zfill(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a vectorised way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1544241, 87526878],
                   [1544242, 92480921]],
                  columns=['A', 'B'])

df.B = df.B.astype(str).str.zfill(10)

#          A           B
# 0  1544241  0087526878
# 1  1544242  0092480921
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [builtin function for padding in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.pad.html),

and you must cast to string before:

```
s.astype(str).str.pad(width=10, side='left', fillchar='0')
```

I tested it and it works.