# Python: Add 0/Zero in a string inside a cell

Tags: python, regex, excel, pandas

I have this sample data in a cell:

```
EmployeeID

2016-CT-1028
2016-CT-1028
2017-CT-1063
2017-CT-1063
2015-CT-948
2015-CT-948
```

So, my problem is how can I add `0` inside this data `2015-CT-948` to 
make it like this `2015-CT-0948`.
I tried this code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d\d+)-(\w\w)-(\d\d\d)')
newlist = list(filter(pattern.match, idList))
```

Just to get the match regex pattern then add the `0` with `zfill()` but its not working. Please, can someone give me an idea on how can I do it. Is there anyway I can do it in regex or in pandas. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach using `zfill`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

def custZfill(val):
    val = val.split("-")
    #alternative split by last -
    #val = val.rsplit("-",1)
    val[-1] = val[-1].zfill(4)
    return "-".join(val)

df = pd.DataFrame({"EmployeeID": ["2016-CT-1028", "2016-CT-1028", 
                                  "2017-CT-1063", "2017-CT-1063", 
                                  "2015-CT-948", "2015-CT-948"]})
print(df["EmployeeID"].apply(custZfill))
```

**Output:**

```
0    2016-CT-1028
1    2016-CT-1028
2    2017-CT-1063
3    2017-CT-1063
4    2015-CT-0948
5    2015-CT-0948
Name: EmployeeID, dtype: object
```

Comment: What if 3 of all your answers is correct? Do I have to choose which one will I mark as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

With pandas it can be solved with `split` instead of regex:

```
df['EmployeeID'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.split('-')[:-1] + [x.split('-')[-1].zfill(4)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

In pandas, you could use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df['EmployeeID'] = df.EmployeeID.str.replace(r'-(\d{3})$', r'-0\1', regex=True)


# Output:

0    2016-CT-1028
1    2016-CT-1028
2    2017-CT-1063
3    2017-CT-1063
4    2015-CT-0948
5    2015-CT-0948
Name: EmployeeID, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

if the format of the id's is strictly defined, you can also use a simple list comprehension to do this job:

```
ids = [
'2017-CT-1063',
'2015-CT-948',
'2015-CT-948'
]

new_ids = [id if len(id) == 12 else id[0:8]+'0'+id[8:] for id in ids]
print(new_ids) 
# ['2017-CT-1063', '2015-CT-0948', '2015-CT-0948']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner:

```
df['EmployeeID'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(xi if i != 2 else '%04d' % int(xi) for i, xi in enumerate(x.split('-'))))
```