# Python pandas dataframe change content based on string length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([111111,123456,12345,234,12,987654],columns=['id'])
```

so if you look at the row 3,4,5 the length of the ids are less than 6

```
id
111111
123456
12345
234
12
987654
```

I want to convert it to below(Basically append zeroes in the front to make it a length of six)

```
id
111111
123456
012345
000234
000012
987654
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
df.id.astype(str).str.pad(6,'left','0')
0    111111
1    123456
2    012345
3    000234
4    000012
5    987654
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Very kind of you.

Comment: @SandhyaThotakura yw :_ happy new year

Answer (score 3):

Try `zfill`, first convert integers to string dtype then use string accessor then zfill:

```
df['id'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
```

Output:

```
0    111111
1    123456
2    012345
3    000234
4    000012
5    987654
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I will go with W-B as I feel his answer is more robust. Thanks for teaching me the concept of zfill(int)

Comment: @SandhyaThotakura Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the datatype to string or else the initial zeroes will be trimmed.
Below is my solution. Hope it helps

```
df = pd.DataFrame([111111,123456,12345,234,12,987654],columns=['id'])
df = df.astype(str)
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==6 else '0'*(6-len(x))+x)

df:
id
111111
123456
012345
000234
000012
987654
```

Comment: Thanks Bhanu for your answer.  You are quick one to answer my question. so 1 upvote.