# List values to have same width

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Python list on int types:

`list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 100]`

I need to get another list of the above list values but with equal width like:

`list2 = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '010', '100']`

I can do this by looping through `list1` values, converting them to strings, finding their lengths and appending 0's in-front of the values but this is a bit long process, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: If you know the width up front, then yes... otherwise, no... what you're doing is basically what you need to be doing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.zfill`

**Ex:**

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 100]
l = len(str(max(list1)))  #Get max width
result = [str(i).zfill(l) for i in list1]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['001', '002', '003', '004', '010', '100']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting:

```
['{:03.0f}'.format(i) for i in list1]
# ['001', '002', '003', '004', '010', '100']
```

Or if you don't know the max width in adavance, you can use `str.rjust`:

```
w = len(max(map(str, list1), key=len))
list2 = [str(i).rjust(w, '0') for i in list1]
```