# Generate a filename in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text, auto-generate

I feel like this question was answered many times before, but i can't find anything.

I have a script which takes a text as command line argument and then generates images with the text in it. It generates image for every word enterd in to the command line but I don't know how to save them. I want to save them like this; first image would be saved as 0001.png, the second one as 0002.png and so on, how can I do this?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I really just don't know how to generate the string in this format (0001) and how to then combine it with ".png" to form a valid file name

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Do you need help figuring out how to save an image to a file? Or do you need help with generating the file names?

Comment: For the leading zeros, look at `str.format()`. Or google "python leading zeros".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use f-strings, you can specify how many 0's the digit should have at minimum:

```
for i in range(1, 1200, 103): # Just to generate bigger numbers
    print(f"{i:04d}.png")
```

Output:

```
0001.png
0104.png
0207.png
0310.png
0413.png
0516.png
0619.png
0722.png
0825.png
0928.png
1031.png
1134.png
```

Comment: This seems like what I need but, how can I make it generate from 0001 instead of 0000?

Comment: Just change the range to start at 1 and go to the input: `for i in range(1, my_input + 1):`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `zfill` method.

Example:

```
n = 10
EXTN = ".png"

filename = str(n).zfill(4) + EXTN
```

Here we put `4` if you want `4` digits in the filename.

Output:

```
0010.png
```