# Making all numbers in a list 3 digit numbers

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list a:

```
a = [45,2, ... ,123,98]
```

How can I convert all numbers to three-digit numbers by adding zeros in front of one or two-digit numbers? This would create a new list like:

```
b = [045,002, ... , 123,098]
```

Comment: Numbers in python do not have leading zeros. Do you want to convert them to strings?

Comment: Yea, exactly. Sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: `[f"{x:03}" for x in arr]`

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension will return what you want

```
[str(n).zfill(3) for n in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

as per this thread [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

you can use str.zfill, you need to turn the numbers into strings first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't represent integers with a leading 0. To do so as strings, do this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  helper = str(a[i])
  while len(helper) < 3:
    helper = "0" + helper
  a[i] = helper
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(num):
    '''
    Adds leading 0s to numbers with < 3 digits, and returns as string
    '''
    if len(str(num))<3:
        num = '0'*(3-len(str(num)))+str(num)
    return str(num)

a = [45,2,123,98]

b = []
for num in a:
    b.append(func(num))

print(b)

>>> ['045', '002', '123', '098']
```

You can also skip the `for` loop and apply the function to each element in the list `a` in the following manner:

```
b = [_ for _ in map(func,a)]
print(b)
>>>  ['045', '002', '123', '098']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and .format to pad zeros:

```
list(map('{:03}'.format, [1,2,3]))                                                                                                                                                  
# ['001', '002', '003']
```