# Putting zeros before a number in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similiar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros), but it is not about the visualization. I have a pandas dataframe with an int column.

```
A
5
43
1200
555
```

And I need to have always 4 digits, as this stands original for a timestamp:

```
00:05
00:43
12:00
05:55
```

How can i work on that column that i have the outcome:

```
0005
0043
1200
0555
```

Comment: So qustion is only about `df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)` ? Not added `:` ?

Comment: the add on with the : is nice, that helped, i changed my question

Comment: Please, don't change the meaning of the question. If you have another question, you should ask it in a separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), but first convert to strings:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
print (df)
      A
0  0005
1  0043
2  1200
3  0555
```

If need `:`:

```
s = df['A'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
df['A'] = s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:]
```

Or:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.zfill(4).map(lambda x: f'{x[:2]}:{x[2:]}')
```

---

```
print (df)
       A
0  00:05
1  00:43
2  12:00
3  05:55
```