# How to add leading zeroes to format?

Tags: ios, python-3.x, format, leading-zero

I need a print function that writes `Loop i / round`, where both values `i` and `round` have to have at least **four digits** `(12 -> 0012)`. It must have the format-method too.

I found the paste formatC and other ways to add leading zeroes but I can't make them work for this case..

It needs to be like this:

```
print('Loop {} / {}'.format('i', 'round'))
```

But with four digit numbers as I said.

Comment: Welome to SO! Could you please show what you have done so far the solve _your_ problem (not some vague statement)? You need to learn how to loop, which is a basic concept. SO isn't a tutorial replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
number_str = str(a_number)
zero_filled_number = number_str.zfill(4)
```

a_number is 12.
zero_filled_number will give you 0012

Answer (score 0):

Use `print("{:02d}".format(1))` as found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134951/14379203) answer.