# How to name files with a count when saving?

Tags: python, save

I am saving images with count function like below

```
count = 0
new_im.save("C:/Users/"+str(count)+".jpg", "JPEG", quality=100, optimize=True, progressive=True)
count += 1
```

The images' names will be 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc.

How to make it save as 001.jpg, 002.jpg, 003.jpg?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
new_im.save("C:/Users/"+'{:0>3}'.format(count)+".jpg", "JPEG", quality=100, optimize=True, progressive=True)
count += 1
```

I have chosen the above so that it looks as similar to your code as possible. But as *Gino Mempin* has pointed out in the comments there are nicer ways to write it. He suggested

```
"C:/Users/{:0>3}.jpg".format(count)
```

I think I would even prefer using *f strings* like so:

```
f"C:/Users/{count:0>3}.jpg"
```