# Binary With X Length for Python

Tags: python

```
x = 3
for i in range(2**x-1):
    print("{0:0xb}".format(i))
```

Is there anyway I can do something like this to match binary length with x?
so that it would print

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

instead of 0 1 01 ... 111
based on my x value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second nested formatting bracket, inside the formatting bracket.

```
x = 3
for i in range(2**x-1):
    print('{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, x))
```

Using f-strings this becomes a bit nicer, similar to your idea really, allowing you to inline `x`:

```
x = 3
for i in range(2**x-1):
    print(f'{i:0{x}b}')
```