# How to create a bin number generator in python?

Tags: python

so as a task I've been asked to create a bin number generator in python where if the user inputs a code template the program has to print out a series of bin numbers. The user must input the code template using the follwing characters n = level range, z = special character(either - or /), s = stack number, c = character. For example, if the user has this as the code template "nnzcczss", z = -, level range = from 1 to 5, and stack number = from 1 to 5.
The output should be:
01-AA-01
01-AA-02
01-AA-03
01-AA-04
01-AA-05
02-AA-01
02-AA-02
... and so on.

so far here is what I have as my code:

```
import re

# C = code template
# Z = special character
# N = level range
# S = stack number

code_template = list(input("Enter code template: "))
special_char = input("Enter special character: ")
level_range = input("Enter level number range: ")
stack_char = input("Enter stack numbers: ")
ct = []
# storing stuff in lists
numidentify1 = [int(num) for num in level_range.split() if num.isdigit()]
lvlrangelist = list(range(numidentify1[0], numidentify1[1] + 1))
numidentify2 = [int(num1) for num1 in stack_char.split() if num1.isdigit()]
stc_chrlist = list(range(numidentify2[0], numidentify2[1] + 1))
# for loops to iterate over and print
for x in code_template:
    new_template = ['A' if x == 'c' else x for x in code_template]
    new_template = [special_char if x == 'z' else x for x in code_template]
    for i in range(len(lvlrangelist)):
       new_template = [lvlrangelist[i] if x == 'n' else x for x in code_template]
       for j in range(len(stc_chrlist)):
               new_template = [stc_chrlist[j] if x == 's' else x for x in code_template]
               print(new_template)
```

However my outputs always come as:

```
['n', 'n', 'z', 'c', 'c', 'z', 1, 1]
['n', 'n', 'z', 'c', 'c', 'z', 2, 2]
```

I am not able to replace the letters with the numbers needed any idea on how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways:

```
code_template = "nnzcczss"
special_char = "-"
level_range = "1 3"
stack_char = "1 3"

# storing stuff in lists
numidentify1 = [int(num) for num in level_range.split() if num.isdigit()]
numidentify2 = [int(num1) for num1 in stack_char.split() if num1.isdigit()]

# for loops to iterate over and print
for i in range(numidentify1[0], numidentify1[1] + 1):
    for j in range(numidentify2[0], numidentify2[1] + 1):
        new_template = code_template.\
            replace('z', special_char).\
            replace('c', 'A'). \
            replace('ss', "%02d" % (j,)).\
            replace('nn', "%02d" % (i,))
        print(new_template)
```

> Output:
> [image]

Comment: What does .\ do ?

Comment: It's explicit line break (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation)

Comment: Oh ok awesome thanks! alsoi what does putting (j,) in this format exactly do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros