# How do i create a number generator but with 0 on the right of the numbers not removed for 2 digit numbers of 1 digit numbers

Tags: python

ran = random.randint(1,999)

print(ran)

some times the output comes as 45 or 5 but I want it to be 045 or 005, how do i do that?

Comment: Your question is about adding leading zeroes, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134951/14507110)

Comment: You are generating integers ... not strings. Integers have no leading zeros ... unless you a) format them when printing or b) convert them to string and print that with leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

you can use python formatter:

```py
print(f"{ran:03d}")
```

This will print the number with leading 0's so that it takes 3 characters.

See this also: [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros#134951).

In Python 2 (and Python 3) you can do:

```
print("%03d"%ran)
```

In Python 3.6+, you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) like this:

```
print(f"{ran:03d}")
```

Comment: From Python 3.6+ you can use f-strings instead of the `%` formatting operator, it is highly encouraged

Answer (score 0):

A number can't have leading zeros in python but a string can, so you would generate random numbers then add the leading zeros as a string.

```py
from random import randint
ran = random.randint(1,999)
print(f"{ran:02d}")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
len = 3-len(str(ran))
for x in range(0, len):
    ran = "0" + ran
print (ran)
```

Comment: There are better ways to do this, also it won't work because you can not take the `len()` of an integer

Comment: Corrected, but yeah, looks like there are more elegant solutions