# How do you keep leading 0s in other columns using them?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns,two are used to calculate the one. I'm using leading 0s for the "waypoint #" and I would like to include them so the Ref # column, its formula  is `=IF(OR([@[GPS colour]] = "O"), "1", "2")& [@[waypoint '#]]`.

[image]

So the Ref # cells would come out as

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/134934/4961700

Comment: `=IF(OR([@[GPS colour]] = "O"), "1", "2")& TEXT([@[waypoint '#]],"000")`

Comment: or: `((@[GPS colour]] <> "O")+1)&TEXT([@[waypoint '#]],"000")` just a little bit shorter.

Comment: Boolean Logic is better!

Answer (score 2):

One needs to use TEXT to keep the format:

```
TEXT([@[waypoint '#]],"000")
```

So:

```
=IF(OR([@[GPS colour]] = "O"), "1", "2")& TEXT([@[waypoint '#]],"000")
```

Also it can be simplified:

```
((@[GPS colour]] <> "O")+1)&TEXT([@[waypoint '#]],"000")
```

Answer (score -1):

To me GPS color looks like a character (O) not a zero (0).

In case there is more than one Character that should be mapped, try this:

[image]

`=IFNA(INDEX(configMapping[Mapping],MATCH([@[GPS colour]],configMapping[GPS color],0)),fallback) & TEXT([@[waypoint '#]],"000")`

where the mapping table is named `configMapping` and the cell I4 is called `fallback`